# Conditional Iteration on a parsed json object using each in groovy

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to create an XML based on the data from a `.json`. So, my `.json` file looks something like:

```
{
  "fruit1":
    {
      "name": "apple",
      "quantity": "three",
      "taste": "good",
      "color": { "walmart": "{{red}}","tj": "{{green}}" }
    },
  "fruit2":
    {
      "name": "banana",
      "quantity": "five",
      "taste": "okay",
      "color": { "walmart": "{{gmo}}","tj": "{{organic}}" }
    }
}
```

I can create the XML just fine with the below code, from the above json

```
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def GenerateXML() {
  def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
  def fileReader = new BufferedReader(
                  new FileReader("/home/workspace/sample.json"))
  def parsedData = jsonSlurper.parse(fileReader)
  def writer = new FileWriter("sample.XML")
  def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
  builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
  writer << builder.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    "friuts"(version:'$number', application: "FunApp"){
      delegate.deployables {
     parsedData.each { index, obj ->
       "fruit"(name:obj.name, quantity:obj.quantity) {
            delegate.taste(obj.taste)
            delegate.color {
            obj.color.each { name, value ->
              it.entry(key:name, value)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

I want to extend this code, such that it looks for particular keys. And if they are present, the loop is performed for those `maps` as well and as such extends the resulting file.

So, if i have the JSON as like so:

```
{"fruit1":
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "quantity": "three",
    "taste": "good",
    "color": { "walmart": "{{red}}","tj": "{{green}}" }
  },
  "fruit2":
  {
    "name": "banana",
    "quantity": "five",
    "taste": "okay",
    "color": { "walmart": "{{gmo}}","tj": "{{organic}}" }
  },
  "chip1":
  {
    "name": "lays",
    "quantity": "one",
    "type": "baked"
  },
  "chip2":
  {
    "name": "somename",
    "quantity": "one",
    "type": "fried"
  }
}
```

I want to add an `IF`, so that it check if any key(s) like `'chip*'` is there. And if yes, perform another iteration. If not just skip that section of logic, and not throw any `err`. like this

```
import groovy.xml.*
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def GenerateXML() {
  def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
  def fileReader = new BufferedReader(
                  new FileReader("/home/okram/workspace/objectsRepo/sample.json"))
  def parsedData = jsonSlurper.parse(fileReader)
  def writer = new FileWriter("sample.XML")
  def builder = new StreamingMarkupBuilder()
  builder.encoding = 'UTF-8'
  writer << builder.bind {
    mkp.xmlDeclaration()
    "fruits"(version:'$number', application: "FunApp"){
     deployables {
     parsedData.each { index, obj ->
       "fruit"(name:obj.name, quantity:obj.quantity) {
            taste(obj.taste)
            color {
            obj.color.each { name, value ->
              it.entry(key:name, value)
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (parsedData.containsKey('chip*')){
      //perform the iteration of the chip* maps
      //to access the corresponding values
      //below code fails, but that is the intent     
      parsedData.<onlyTheOnesPassing>.each { index1, obj1 -> 
         "Chips"(name:obj1.name, quantity:obj1.quantity) {
           type(obj1.type)
         }

      } 

      }

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the same dificult, but on **Javascript** language, if the logic help you, here what I made:

**There are two ways:**

You can use the library Lodash on the "get" here: [Lodash get](https://lodash.com/docs/#get) or the another one "has": [Lodash has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#has).

With they you can put the object and the path and check if there is one without getting any error.

Examples:

```js
_.has(object, 'chip1.name');
// => false

_.has(object, 'fruit1');
// => true
```

Or you can put the code of the methods here:

```js
// Recursively checks the nested properties of an object and returns the
 // object property in case it exists.
 static get(obj, key) {
  return key.split(".").reduce(function (o, x) {
   return (typeof o == "undefined" || o === null) ? o : o[x];
  }, obj);
 }

 // Recursively checks the nested properties of an object and returns
 //true in case it exists.
 static has(obj, key) {
  return key.split(".").every(function (x) {
   if (typeof obj != "object" || obj === null || !x in obj)
   return false;
   obj = obj[x];
   return true;
  });
 }
```

I hope it helps! :)